# Get dates of the MSSQL Database Transaction Log records

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, date

I am wondering if there is a way not just to get the transaction log (e.g. using `fn_dblog`), but also get the date for the start of execution for each of the transactions recorded?

It's okay to get any amount of extra uninteresting data as long as I get the date or timestamp of the transaction execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very detailed in exactly what you want, but [How to read and interpret the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/) has some very good information about interpreting the SQL Server log.

Specifically relating to finding the start of a transaction (from the above post):

> The first think I will do will be to look at the LOP_BEGIN_XACT
>   operations. This log record marks the beginning of a transaction and
>   is very important in log analysis because is the only log record that
>   contains the date and time when the transaction started, and also
>   contains the SID of the user that had issued the statement. Here is
>   how I query for these operations:

```
select [Current LSN], [Operation], [Transaction ID], [Parent Transaction ID],
    [Begin Time], [Transaction Name], [Transaction SID]
from fn_dblog(null, null)
where [Operation] = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even if it did, it would include things like backups, index rebuilds, statistics updates, etc. Not sure that’s be totally useful by itself.

Zoom out a little - what’s the problem you’re trying to solve, and there may be a better answer to a different question?

Comment: It's okay to get any amount of extra uninteresting data as long as I get the date or timestamp of the transaction execution.